# How to activate verbosity in Langchain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I'm using Langchain 0.0.345. I cannot get a verbose output of what's going on under the hood using the [LCEL approach](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/) to chain building.

I have this code:

```py
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser
from langchain.globals import set_verbose

set_verbose(True)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("tell me a joke about {topic}")
model = ChatOpenAI()
output_parser = StrOutputParser()

chain = prompt | model | output_parser

chain.invoke({"topic": "ice cream"})
```

According to the [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/debugging) using `set_verbose` is the way to have a verbose output showing intermediate steps, prompt builds etc. But the output of this script is just a string without any intermediate steps.
Actually, the module `langchain.globals` does not appear even mentioned in [the API documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/v0.0.345/search.html?q=langchain.globals).

I have also tried setting the `verbose=True` parameter in the model creation, but it also does not work. This used to work with the former approach building with classes and so.

How is the recommended and current approach to have the output logged so you can understand what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a callback handler to the `invoke` method's configuration.

#### Like this:

```
from langchain.callbacks.tracers import ConsoleCallbackHandler

# ...your code

chain.invoke({"topic": "ice cream"}, config={'callbacks': [ConsoleCallbackHandler()]})
```

###### Code with change incorporated:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser
from langchain.callbacks.tracers import ConsoleCallbackHandler

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("tell me a joke about {topic}")
model = ChatOpenAI()
output_parser = StrOutputParser()

chain = prompt | model | output_parser

chain.invoke({"topic": "ice cream"}, config={'callbacks': [ConsoleCallbackHandler()]})
```

The output isn't the same as the original "verbose mode", but this is the closest alternative.

#### Alternatives

###### For more targeted output or less "verbosity"

Try attaching a callback handler to specific objects. For example:

```
ChatOpenAI().with_config({'callbacks': [ConsoleCallbackHandler()]})
```

You can learn more about customizing callbacks [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/callbacks/)

###### For high verbosity

Global debug still works with LCEL:

```
from langchain.globals import set_debug

set_debug(True)

# your code
```

###### For a GUI

you can use [weights and biases or langsmith](https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/debugging)

Comment: Thanks it works. I have some comments/doubts, though. I'll leave as separate comments if you want to add on them (perhaps to polish the answer?)

Comment: It's curious how the `set_verbose(True)` does not work. I didn't continue to use the `set_debug` version, therefore I didn't realise that. Is it a hint that the former might soon be also deprecated?

Comment: I didn't know the `with_config` method. I tried the `bind(callbacks=[...])` but it didn't work. Do you have an idea on what's the difference between both (and rationale for it)? Actually I didn't find any mention to `with_config` in the current documentation... Regarding the callbacks documentation, I had read it, but unfortunately it does not contain information about how to use this within the LCEL framework, therefore my question. Your example is the first one I see. Thanks for that!

Comment: To put it kindly, LCEL docs are... evolving :). But the code docstrings are much better. `with_config` is a method of `Runnable` that returns a `RunnableBinding`. `RunnableBinding` is effectively a decorator for a `Runnable` that you use to bind things to `Runnable`. `with_config` takes a `RunnableConfig`, which is the class that defines the configuration attributes available to a runnable.  You can see a handy list of these in the docstring! `from langchain_core.runnables.config import RunnableConfig`. This may explain why bind doesn't work for you: you want to bind a `RunnableConfig`.

Comment: Hopefully that's clear, given length limits of comments  . For a higher-level view, you can find limited documentation on `with_config` [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/how_to/configure), but code is IMO more clear than the docs. 
I welcome corrections to the above from anyone more familiar with the codebase.

To answer your second Q: it's not clear `verbose` will be deprecated. In fact there's [an open issue proposing to make it work again with LCEL](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/14135)

Answer (score 3):

According to the document (https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/debugging), try this

```py
from langchain.globals import set_verbose, set_debug

set_debug(True)
set_verbose(True)
```

All the intermediate message will be printed out